# Octopus not picking up NuGet packages from feed

Tags: teamcity, octopus-deploy

I'm using TeamCity 9.0 Enterprise and Octopus Deploy 1.6.3.1723

For some reason, Octopus will not pick up any packages from the Nuget feed - this has started happening on all projects, since the upgrade.

My log output is the following:

```
[11:51:38] :         [Octopus Deploy] Handshaking with Octopus server: http://x.x.com/api
[11:51:41] :         [Octopus Deploy] Handshake successful. Octopus version: 1.6.3.1723; API version: 2.0.0
[11:51:41] :         [Octopus Deploy] Finding environments...
[11:51:41] :         [Octopus Deploy] Finding steps for project...
[11:51:41] :         [Octopus Deploy] Resolving NuGet package versions...
[11:51:41] :         [Octopus Deploy]   - Finding latest NuGet package for step: Deploy web application
[11:51:41] :         [Octopus Deploy] There are no available packages named 'APP-MVC-BookingTool'.
```

The strange and confusing thing is that if I run the exact same command  that is executed by TC manually from the command line on the server, it works perfectly.  It smells like a permissions thing, but I'm really not sure where to start looking for symptoms of this as there's no obvious errors in any log files.

Thanks,

Martin